# Running `bundle install`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Recently, sometimes running `bundle install` hangs.  The output is not what I usually see.  I'm used to seeing this:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
```

But I know something's up when I see this:

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
```

And this is where it hangs.

What's weird is that sometimes bundle works normally, and sometimes it fails.  I can't accurately predict when it will pass or fail.

`bundle update` works as normal, and I can use it to get around this.  But this isn't ideal, because I don't necessarily want to update all the gems!  I'm trying to contribute to a group project and don't want to accidentally break anything by updating a gem that I don't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ack, this isn't really an issue.  I let `bundle` run for a few minutes, and it eventually worked.  It just appeared like it was hanging.

Then I looked a little more and found [this thoughtbot post on the subject](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/fetching-source-index-for-http-rubygems-org).